# How to change the titlespacing of \chapter*{}?

Tags: chapters, titlesec, starred-version

I use this code to change the spacing of `\chapter{}`:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{15pt}
```

How can I change the spacing of the starred version `\chapter*{}`?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{50pt}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter, numberless}{0pt}{-50pt}{50pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `numberless` key (see §3.8, Extended Settings, pp.9-10 in the documentation). This code makes the unnumbered chapters titles appear at the  same distance from thetop as the  numbers of numbered chapters :

```
  \documentclass{report}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]{\filright\bfseries}{\huge\chaptername~\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter}{0pt}{25pt}{50pt}
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[hang]{\filright\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter, numberless}{0pt}{20pt}{50pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}

\chapter{A First Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I understand. You misunderstood me: you have to write in the preamble both `\titlespacing*{name=\chapter}…` and `\titlespacing*{name=\chapter, numberless}…`.

Comment: I updated the MWE but it is not working. I have `-100pt` and the top spacing has not changed in the slightest.

Comment: However, it works for numbered chapters?

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to reduce the top and bottom spacing

Comment: It works if you also define `\titleformat`. Please see if my updated code corresponds to what you want.

Comment: Latex is so damn quirky! Thanks!